# Cannot resolve Neo4j annotations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to import various Neo4j annotations in Eclipse with Maven

I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get:

```
The import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch cannot be resolved
```

when I try to import `@Fetch`, `@RelatedTo` and `@GraphId`. Curiously eclipse shows that the annotations `@Query`, and `@QueryResult` are present on org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation, but only those two and none of the other annotations. All the documentation I can find says the annotations should be there, but it just looks are if they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the spring-data-neo4j.jar, extracted it, and it appears the annotations are not there. I changed to the 3.4.1 release and everything's ok.

Update.

This problem was actually because the quick start example for using neo4j on the Spring website is actually using annotations that are no longer supported by Neo4j 4 whilst showing the dependency to use as Neo4j 4.

Neo4J 4 doesn't use these annotations anymore.